# Create TXT from XML using XSLT - display elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create text file from xml using xslt, and i have a problem.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>

  <płytoteka>
  <bestseller rok="2015">
     <płyta id="p01">
        <gatunek>Pop&amp;Rock</gatunek>
        <tytuł>Atramentowa</tytuł>
        <wykonawca>Celińska Stanisława</wykonawca>
        <data_premiery>2015-05-08</data_premiery>
        <cena>37.49</cena>
        <rok_nagrania>2015</rok_nagrania>
        <czas_trwania>51:19</czas_trwania>
        <czas_od_premiery>P222D</czas_od_premiery>
        <dostepnosc mp3="1" cd="0" dvd="1"/>
        <playlista>
           <utwór>Czerń i biel<czas>3:27</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Czy o kimś ktoś<czas>2:17</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Atramentowa rumba<czas>5:16</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Do rycerzy, do szlachty, do mieszczan<czas>3:22</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Drzwi odemknij<czas>3:21</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Moje życie, twoje życie<czas>3:19</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Obfitość<czas>3:20</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Jego portret<czas>3:15</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>I znowu on<czas>3:11</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Nie strasz<czas>3:55</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Smuteczku mój<czas>3:44</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Szeptem do mnie mów<czas>3:33</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Wielka słota<czas>3:11</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Wakacje z deszczem<czas>2:59</czas>
           </utwór>
           <utwór>Pieśń cygańska<czas>3:09</czas>
           </utwór>
        </playlista>
     </płyta>
  </bestseller>
  </płytoteka>
  </document>
```

Next is my xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.), '')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>TXT&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płytoteka">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bestseller"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bestseller">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>BESTSELLER:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;',./@rok,'&#xA;')" />
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="płyta"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płyta">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>PLYTA:&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Gatunek:&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gatunek"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Tytul: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tytuł"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Wykonawca: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wykonawca"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Data premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Cena: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cena"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Rok nagrania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rok_nagrania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas trwania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_trwania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas od premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_od_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="playlista"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="playlista">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;UTWORY:&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="utwór">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my output:

```
TXT

BESTSELLER:     2015


PLYTA:
Gatunek:    Pop&Rock
Tytul:  Atramentowa
Wykonawca:  Celińska Stanisława
Data premiery:  2015-05-08
Cena:   37.49
Rok nagrania:   2015
Czas trwania:   51:19
Czas od premiery:   P222D

    UTWORY:
    Czerń i biel3:27
           Czy o kimś ktoś2:17
           Atramentowa rumba5:16
           Do rycerzy, do szlachty, do mieszczan3:22
           Drzwi odemknij3:21
           Moje życie, twoje życie3:19
           Obfitość3:20
           Jego portret3:15
           I znowu on3:11
           Nie strasz3:55
           Smuteczku mój3:44
           Szeptem do mnie mów3:33
           Wielka słota3:11
           Wakacje z deszczem2:59
           Pieśń cygańska3:09
```

And the problem is about elements "utwór" and "czas" from the xml file, this elements i want to display in the txt output, more divided, for example:

```
UTWORY:
        Czerń i biel     3:27
               Czy o kimś ktoś     2:17
               Atramentowa rumba     5:16
               Do rycerzy, do szlachty, do mieszczan     3:22
               Drzwi odemknij     3:21
               Moje życie, twoje życie     3:19
               Obfitość     3:20
               Jego portret     3:15
               I znowu on     3:11
               Nie strasz     3:55
               Smuteczku mój     3:44
               Szeptem do mnie mów     3:33
               Wielka słota     3:11
               Wakacje z deszczem     2:59
               Pieśń cygańska     3:09
```

I just want to make space between this elements or even better display this two elements in some kind of order, just to be pleasing to the eyes, like:

```
    UTWORY:
               Czerń i biel                              3:27
               Czy o kimś ktoś                           2:17
               Atramentowa rumba                         5:16
               Do rycerzy, do szlachty, do mieszczan     3:22
               Drzwi odemknij                            3:21
               Moje życie, twoje życie                   3:19
               Obfitość                                  3:20
               Jego portret                              3:15
               I znowu on                                3:11
               Nie strasz                                3:55
               Smuteczku mój                             3:44
               Szeptem do mnie mów                       3:33
               Wielka słota                              3:11
               Wakacje z deszczem                        2:59
               Pieśń cygańska                            3:09
```

is it even possible?
I am using to transform http://xsltransform.net

One more thing, i have to apologise for some Polish words, i was to lazy to translate some names of elements to english, and i know if everything would be in english the files will be more clearly, but in the end, it is just about xslt logic. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you process the child elements, as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.), '')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>TXT&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płytoteka">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bestseller"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bestseller">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>BESTSELLER:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;',./@rok,'&#xA;')" />
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="płyta"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płyta">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>PLYTA:&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Gatunek:&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gatunek"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Tytul: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tytuł"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Wykonawca: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wykonawca"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Data premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Cena: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cena"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Rok nagrania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rok_nagrania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas trwania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_trwania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas od premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_od_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="playlista"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="playlista">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;UTWORY:&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="utwór"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="utwór">
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="utwór/czas">
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

then you can at least separate the text from the duration. Example at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWm.

If you use XSLT 2.0 then you can use the library functx as in http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWm/1, it does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">

<xsl:import href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.), '')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>TXT&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płytoteka">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bestseller"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bestseller">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>BESTSELLER:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;&#x9;',./@rok,'&#xA;')" />
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="płyta"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="płyta">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>PLYTA:&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Gatunek:&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gatunek"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Tytul: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tytuł"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Wykonawca: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wykonawca"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Data premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Cena: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cena"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Rok nagrania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rok_nagrania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas trwania: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_trwania"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Czas od premiery: &#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="czas_od_premiery"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="playlista"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="playlista">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;UTWORY:&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="utwór"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="utwór">
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="utwór/text()[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="functx:pad-string-to-length(., ' ', max(../../utwór/text()[1]/string-length()))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="utwór/czas">
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>



 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

to format the data better.